# Custom block on success page for my Payment Method

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, blocks, payment-methods

I'm developing a custom payment method and I'd like it to show some info (related to the payment method) on the success page.

How can I do this?

I've tried appending the block to the checkout_onepage_success content but I got nothing but errors.

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.success">
            <action method="setChild">
                <block type="checkbuy/success" name="checkbuy.success" template="checkbuy/success.phtml" />
            </action>
        </reference>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

**EDIT:**
I also tried using `<action method="append">` but it caused big PHP errors.

**EDIT 2:**
I need the block only to be shown when my payment method is selected, I don't want to override the standard success page if the client uses other payment method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it!!

I was overriding the layout to `checkout_onepage_success` and that was the reason my block was showing in every payment method. So I defined the layout just for my module's payment success page and called the standard onepage_success block for checkout and then my custom information block.

Here's my final layout file:

```
<checkbuy_payment_success translate="label">
    <reference name="root">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>page/1column.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>
    <reference name="content">
        <block type="checkout/onepage_success" name="checkout.success" template="checkout/success.phtml"/>
        <block type="checkbuy/success" name="checkbuy.success" />
    </reference>
</checkbuy_payment_success>
```

Answer (score 1):

Pleas try this:

```
<checkout_onepage_success translate="label">
    <reference name="content">
        <reference name="checkout.success">
                <block type="checkbuy/success" name="checkbuy.success" template="checkbuy/success.phtml" />
        </reference>
    </reference>
</checkout_onepage_success>
```

Then on succcess.phtml call this child block by

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(checkbuy.success) ;?>
```

Comment: It works!! Sadly I can't use this solution because the payment method is going to be a redistributable module so I can't edit success.phtml (which is part of magento core files).

Comment: What is full path to success.phtml ? Is it located in frontend/base/default? If yes you can copy success.phtml to your current theme and edit it. 
Otherwise you can change template for checkout.success block:
     <reference name="checkout.success">
        <action method="setTemplate">
            <template>mymodule/mysuccess.phtml</template>
        </action>
    </reference>

Comment: The full path to the success.phtml file is `frontend/base/default/template/checkout/success.phtml`

But doesn't that solution show mysuccess.phtml for every payment method? I'd like it to be shown (if possible) only when you select my payment method.

Comment: need copy the file to frontend/YourPackage/YourTheme/template/checkout/success.phtml

Comment: That way it works, but Magento shows my version of success.phtml with every payment method. I need it only to appear when the client uses my module for payment.

Thanks a lot for your comments, they're helping me a lot. :)